# Async http request from Play action

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using Play 2.6-RC2 and have an action which needs to call an external component over http (`POST`).

I am having problems understanding how the action should be implemented and how I get the response from the `POST` request.

This is what I currently have, but am lost as how to proceed:

```
class ABCController @Inject()
(
  cc: ControllerComponents,
  langs: Langs,
  messagesApi: MessagesApi,
  ws: WSClient
) extends AbstractController(cc) with I18nSupport {

   def submit = Action.async { implicit request: Request[_] => {
     val res = ws.url("http://127.0.0.1:8111/abc").post("test")
     // How do I get the POST  response and return async??
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ! to get a better answer it would help saying what have you tried till now, what would you like to do with the response. Giving and example will be best

Comment: Haven't tried anything that compiled :-)

Comment: but what would you like to do with the `res` ? want to just send it or extract some data from it?

Comment: Extract the result and use this (should be a JSON string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the injected WSClient to `play.api.libs.ws.WSClient` then you will get the same behaviour as previously in 2.5, `post` will return `Future[WSResponse]` and you may use `map` on this.

```
class ABCController @Inject()
(
  cc: ControllerComponents,
  langs: Langs,
  messagesApi: MessagesApi,
  ws: play.api.libs.ws.WSClient
) extends AbstractController(cc) with I18nSupport {
```

Answer (score 0):

The ws.url method returns a Future[WSResponse], which you need to map to resolve. So I think you need to do something like this:

```
def submit = Action.async { implicit request: Request[_] => {
 val res:Future[WSResponse] = ws.url("http://127.0.0.1:8111/abc").post("test")
 res.map(wsres => { 
   Ok(wsres.json)
 })
}
```

See Processing the Response section: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaWS

Comment: I am using 2.6 where this is no longer the case and its this new object I don't understand how to work with - its from 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.0-RC2/ScalaWS

Comment: As far as I can see, the above code should work fine (even in RC2). Which part is troubling you?

Comment: `ws.url` returns `CompletionStage[WSResponse]` and not `Future[WSResponse]`.
The objects are from `play.libs.ws` and not from `play.api.libs.ws` - same with the injected `WSClient`.

Comment: ah but does the .post call not return a Future[WSResponse]?

Comment: Nope - `CompletionStage[WSResponse]`

Comment: even so - I believe you should be able to map the result of the .post call and parse your json from the response (as in the RC2 documentation). Are you saying that you've tried this and it doesn't work?

Comment: So you are saying the examples in the docs are wrong then? From what I can see CompletionStage is more related to Java code. I can't find any examples in Scala.